# How can I get perl to work with gmail chat?

Tags: perl, xmpp, google-talk

I tried [this](http://blogs.perl.org/users/marco_fontani/2010/03/google-talk-with-perl.html) and [this](https://www.gridpp.ac.uk/wiki/Nagios_jabber_notification). But it just doesn't work. `AuthSend` returns empty array. Probably I should provide you with some code to talk about:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::XMPP;
use Data::Dumper;

my $username = 'USERNAME';
my $password = 'PASSWORD';
my $connection = new Net::XMPP::Client;
my $r = $connection->Connect(
    hostname => 'talk.google.com',
    port => 5222,
    componentname => 'gmail.com',
    connectiontype => 'tcpip',
    tls => 1
);
say Dumper $r;
my @r = $connection->AuthSend(
    username => $username,
    password => $password,
    resource => 'test'
);
say Dumper \@r;
```

Comment: Try port 5223: https://support.google.com/talk/answer/24074?hl=en

Comment: @toolic It doesn't authenticate.

Comment: @RobEarl In this case `Connect` returns `undef`.

Answer (score -1):

You may try [Net::XMPP::Client::GTalk](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::XMPP::Client::GTalk).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use Net::XMPP::Client::GTalk;

my $username = 'USERNAME';
my $password = 'PASSWORD';

# does all the connection-handling and authentication at once
my $client = Net::XMPP::Client::GTalk->new(
    USERNAME => $username,
    PASSWORD => $password,
);

say Dumper($client);
```